# Is there an easy way to do a Master Grid View that links to a Detail grid view?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I've been struggling with trying to get this to work.  Does anybody know of a easy to follow tutorial that shows the Master/Detail grid view?
Thanks.  I'm a very novice programmer.
I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with c#.

Comment: I found an easy to use tutorial that does not require any programming.  Also has many screen shots. http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/asp.net-2.0/displaying-master-detail-data-on-the-same-page.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BindingSource class. Could you provide the kind of data you want to be displayed (DataTable, custom objects) ?

[EDIT]

[MSDN How To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx)

Comment: The page I need will be in asp.net, so the MSDN How To http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx will not work for me.
I did find this Visual C# Tutorial: http://www.asp.net/(S(pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3))/learn/data-access/tutorial-10-cs.aspx .
I was looking for another good example.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I need to be able to select one record, and open the details of another table either on the same page, or redirected to a new page.  The tables are linked through a primary key/foreign key relationship.

Comment: Maybe you should replace the winforms tag by an asp.net tag, shouldn't you ?